# Skip Microsoft's message at beginning of a file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

When running a vbs script from a bat file, it is sometimes written in header output file

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. Tous droits r‚serv‚s
example: cscript myvbs.vbs file.txt >result.txt
```

I know that doing more +2 on the output file, I am able to ignore that. Nevetheless I'd like to know if it is possible to do that differently.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the  `//Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time`

```
C:\>cscript
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
 //Job:xxxx  Execute a WSF job
 //Logo      Display logo (default)
 //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time
 //S         Save current command line options for this user
 //T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run
 //X         Execute script in debugger
 //U         Use Unicode for redirected I/O from the console
```

Comment: Thank you for all details. It's OK!

Answer (score 0):

It worth to mention the `//S` option which will save the subsequent options specified at command line for the current user.
So instead of calling `cscript //Nologo` a hundred times, just call `cscript //S //Nologo` in the first place, before the subsequent cscript calls which will launch the actual VBS scripts. This will default cscript to use the Nologo flag every time it will be invoked.
Thanks for your attention, hope it will help you ;-).